# Why does it give me IndexError: list index out of range for this piece of code? I double-checked

Tags: python, list

Help I tried running this piece of code yet it keeps saying list index out of range. Whenever I go to the last list item it just gives that error. Everything else works fine. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?
'

```
conversations = ['favouriteFood', 'anyPets', 'idealGift', 'favouriteShow']


def conversationStarter():

        
    if conversations[1] == 'favouriteFood':
        conversations.remove('favouriteFood')
        answer1 = input('What is your favourite food? My favourite food is codewords.')
        answer2 = input('Wow! I love eating ' + answer1.lower() + ' too! What is your second favourite?')
        print('Really? I never really learnt to like ' + answer2.lower() + ', but I will have a go!')
        conversationStarter()
    elif conversations[1] == 'anyPets':
        conversations.remove('anyPets')
        answer = input('Hey hey hey! Do you have any pets? I do, of course, a pet python! Do you have any pets?')
        if answer == 'yes':
            answer = input('Really! What kind of pet do you own?')
            print('Wow! I would love to have a ' + answer.lower() + ' someday!')
            conversationStarter()
        if answer == 'no':
            print('Oh. OK! However, I highly recommend a pet, they make you happier!')
            conversationStarter()
    elif conversations[1] == 'idealGift':
        conversations.remove('idealGift')
        answer = input('What is your most ideal gift for the New Year?')
        print('WHAT? You think of a ' + answer.lower() + ' as an ideal gift? I would rather like a Python code.')
        conversationStarter()
    elif conversations[1] == 'favouriteShow':
        conversations.remove('favouriteShow')
        answer = input('What is your favourite movie or TV film?')
        print('Wait what? I never heard of ' + answer + '. I should watch it! I love watching Python tutorials though.')
        conversationStarter()

def greetingMenu():
    print('Welcome to the NewYearPyChat.home file. Do you want a conversation?')
    answer = input("Please answer 'yes' or 'no'.")
    if answer == 'yes':
        print('Amazing! Let us start chatting then!')
        conversationStarter()
    elif answer == 'no':
        print('Oh. Try again next time.')
        greetingMenu()
    else:
        print('What are you saying?')
        greetingMenu()


        
    

greetingMenu()
print('And by the way, my name is PyChat if you have not guessed already.')
```

I tried looking at the piece of code and fixing bits and deleting nearly all of it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the error being thrown? What does the error say precisely? Which parts of your code have you checked over and tried deleting?

Comment: You keep removing things from the list. Eventually it will only have 1 element, and `[1]` will be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the **second** element of the array in each of your if-elif checks. Change each instance of `conversations[1]` to `conversations[0]` and you should see the results you're looking for.

Comment: Then it will get an error when the list is empty.